# ui-grid Pagination not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm just in the beginning of implementing ui-grid into my application.

I've been following the [official ui-grid documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination) for the pagination feature, and so far I couldn't make it quite work.

Although it's showing the pagination controls, it's not 'respecting' the parameters I'm inputting in the code, as follows:

```
$scope.setGrid = function () {

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enablePagination: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        paginationPageSize: 10,
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: false,
        enablePaginationControls: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { name: 'name', field: 'name', type:'object', enableCellEdit: false },
            { name: 'lastName', field: 'last_name', type: 'object', enableCellEdit: false },
            { name: 'email', field: 'email', type: 'object', enableCellEdit: false },
            { name: 'creationDate', field: 'created', type: 'object', enableCellEdit: false, cellFilter: 'date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"'},
            { name: 'userActive', enableCellEdit: false, field: 'active', type: 'boolean'}

        ],
        data: $scope.users
    }
}
```

And in the HTML view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <rd-widget-body classes="medium no-padding">
        <div id="grid1" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
    </rd-widget-body>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my modules block:

```
angular.module('RDash', [   
 'ui.bootstrap', 
 'ui.router', 
 'ngCookies',
 'ngRoute',
 'ngResource',
 'doowb.angular-pusher',
 'xeditable',
 'ui.grid',
 'ui.grid.edit',
 'ui.grid.pagination',
 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 
 'ui.grid.selection'
 ]);
```

The problem that is happening is that in my grid, although it's configured and accepting pagination, the pagination controls are disabled, and not acccepting the pageSize and paginationPagesSize that have been configured.

It's showing instead, all the items in my dataset (35 items so far for this test) and in the Items Per Page dropdown it's showing 250|500|1000, which seems to be the default configuration.

It seems that I am forgetting to call some method to 'fire up' the entire thing, but I'm unsure.

I did find many examples of pagination out there, [such as this one](http://plnkr.co/edit/UttxPkXG8fYQDX85fnyZ?p=preview), they are all pretty straightforward, but still I can't seem to make it work. The pagination, although the controls are being shown, it's completely disabled, and not taking the parameters I have set.

My ui-grid version is  v4.0.11 (2017-11-20), as taken from the CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was wrong. All the parameters are correct, the problem was that the method $scope.setGrid() in my code was being called before the time the code was actually binding the dataset into  $scope.gridOptions.data. I changed the runtime, to make it be called only when the actual binding takes place and everything started working.